# how to make logic for checking braces for conditional statements in java?

Tags: java, pmd

I am practicing with PMD plug-in and i want to write a rule in java for checking braces for if, while and for loops. Any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use an IDE that checks it for you and get it over with?  I would never write code to do such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a matter or understanding the ASTs.  For example, if the body of a while statement has curly braces it will be a Block.  If not, it will be some other kind of statement.

In fact, the ["How to write a PMD rule"](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/howtowritearule.html) page uses while statement / curly braces as its example.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/). It may be overkill for just brace matching, but useful when you want to validate other parts of the grammer, like the if/while loops.

Comment: Can't we write a simple logic to find whether condition is maintained braces?